# What's the difference between these two java code?

Tags: java, exception

if without the `throws IllegalArgumentException`, I can still throw exception that catched by the catch block in the main fucntion, why I need `throws IllegalArgumentException`??

```
public class ExceptionsTest {
    public static void funcThrowsException(int n) throws IllegalArgumentException{
        if(n == 0){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("ex");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            funcThrowsException(0);
        }catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

```
public class ExceptionsTest {
    public static void funcThrowsException(int n){
        if(n == 0){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("ex");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            funcThrowsException(0);
        }catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

Their output are same:

```
ex

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I don't know why we need throws keywords

Comment: depending on the type of Exception, throws is (or isn't) mandatory. IllegalArgumentException is a subclass of RuntimeException, and for RuntimeException, it is not required to put 'throws' in the method signature. For non-RuntimeException Exceptions, it is required.

Comment: check [Understanding checked vs unchecked exceptions in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/understanding-checked-vs-unchecked-exceptions-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't know why we need throws keywords

In this case, you don't - because `IllegalArgumentException` extends `RuntimeException`. It's therefore not a *checked exception*, and doesn't need to be declared in a method that throws it.

See the [Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html) for more details on when you need to use a `throws` declaration.

Comment: Thank you,


When a checked exception is thrown, only callers who can handle it properly should catch it with a try/catch.

A runtime exception, should not be caught in the program. If you catch it, you run the risk that a bug in the code will be hidden from view at runtime.

Is my understanding right?

Comment: @miaosun: Not necessarily - you certainly *can* catch RuntimeExceptions, and *sometimes* that's appropriate... but it's less common.